# search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed"

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET /total_user_amount/_search
{

  "query": {

    "terms": {

      "orderId": [

        "111",

        "2222"

       #  total  more than  80,000 values  

      ]

    }

  },

    "size": 0, 

  "aggs": {

    "sum_amount": {

      "sum": {

        "field": "score"

      }

    }

  }

}
```

there has some question:

when the values in orderId  more than  80,000 values  ,  there is  error info  search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed",

elastic search 7.15,

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the terms array into smaller arrays, say with 50K ids each (or smaller as you see fit), like below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "orderId": [
              "111",
              ....
              "50000"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "orderId": [
              "50001",
              ....
              "6666"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sum_amount": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when the number of values exceed a particular limit.The approach that i recommend is dividing the order_list into multiple subsets and summing it up at the end.

> When working with large datasets and splitting them into subsets, we need to consider the performance and resource limitations of the Elasticsearch cluster. It's important to monitor the performance and optimize the script to the specific needs.

Sample .py script

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
client = Elasticsearch()

order_list = [...] 
subset_size = 10000
order_subsets = [order_list[i:i+subset_size] for i in range(0, len(order_list), subset_size)]

# Perform search and aggregation for each subset
aggregation_results = []
for subset in order_subsets:
    query = {
        "query": {
            "regexp": {
                "orderId": {
                    "value": "|".join(subset)
                }
            }
        },
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
            "sum_amount": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "score"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    result = client.search(index="your_index_name", body=query)
    
    
    aggregation_results.append(result["aggregations"]["sum_amount"]["value"])

# Calculate the total sum from all subsets
total_sum = sum(aggregation_results)
print("Total sum: ", total_sum)
```